# LCM of n-1 elements in SML

Tags: sml, lcm

I have the following functions to calculate the LCM of all elements from a list. Are there any hints for calculating every LCM of each (n-1) subsets and store them in a list instead?

```
fun modulo (_,0) = 0
  | modulo (0,_) = 0
  | modulo (x,y) = if y > x then x else
    let
      fun getMod(z) = if z >= y then getMod(z-y) else z
    in
      getMod(x)
    end

fun lcm (0,_) = 0
  | lcm (_,0) = 0
  | lcm (x,y) = 
    let
      fun findLcm (base,mult,v) =
          if modulo(mult,v) = 0
          then mult
          else findLcm(base,mult+base,v)
    in
      if x > y then findLcm(x,x,y) else findLcm(y,y,x)
    end

fun ekp(xs) =
    case xs of
         []       => 1
       | (x::xs') => lcm(x,ekp(xs'))
```

Comment: What's an *(n-1) subset*? Try and provide an example. This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "*the (n-1) subsets of S*" means *{ S\{x} | x ∈ S }*, the set of subsets of *S* where one element has been removed for each element of *S*, you can trivially generate the *least common multiple* of each of those by first generating the sets and then applying the *least common multiple* algorithm to each subset.

Here's a shorter way to generate the *least common multiple*:

```
fun gcd (a, 0) = a
  | gcd (a, b) = gcd (b, a mod b)

fun lcm (a, b) = (a * b) div (gcd (a, b))

val lcm_list = foldl lcm 1
```

The function `lcm_list` corresponds to your function `ekp`.

To get a list of subsets where one element is removed from each (assuming no duplicates):

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)
fun subsets1 [] = []
  | subsets1 (x::xs) = xs :: map (curry op:: x) (subsets1 xs)
```

And to generate the *least common multiple* of each of those subsets,

```
- subsets1 [3,4,5];
> val it = [[4, 5], [3, 5], [3, 4]] : int list list
- map lcm_list (subsets1 [3,4,5]);
> val it = [20, 15, 12] : int list
```

That is, *the (n-1) subsets of {3,4,5}* is found to be *{ {4,5}, {3,5}, {3,4} }*, and the *least common multiple* of each of those *(n-1) subsets* is *{ lcm(4, 5), lcm(3, 5), lcm(3, 4) } = { 20, 15, 12 }*. At this point, some redundant work may have been carried out. For any larger list, the set of subsets will have a large amount of overlap. For example,

```
- subsets1 [3,4,5,6,7,8];
> val it =
    [ [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      [3, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      [3, 4, 6, 7, 8],
      [3, 4, 5, 7, 8],
      [3, 4, 5, 6, 8],
      [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] ] : int list list
```

Using the method above, we would calculate `lcm (3, 4)` = 12 four times, `lcm (12, 5)` = 60 three times, etc. You may benefit from a speed-up by [applying memoization](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/techniques/memoization.htm) to the `lcm` function, although it isn't terribly expensive.